# Could not find resource_retriever after catkin-make command. How to fix it?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin-make

How to fix it:

```
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/user/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/user/catkin_ws/devel  
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic  
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic  
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 

-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2  
-- Using Debian Python package layout  
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy  
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON  
-- Call enable_testing()  
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR:  
 /home/user/catkin_ws/build/test_results  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built  
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built  
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17")   
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7  
-- catkin 0.7.29  
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on  
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:  
-- ~~  - dope  
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'dope'    
-- ==> add_subdirectory(dope)  
-- Could NOT find resource_retriever (missing: resource_retriever_DIR)  
-- Could not find the required component 'resource_retriever'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.  
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):  
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "resource_retriever" with any of the following names:  

    resource_retrieverConfig.cmake
    resource_retriever-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "resource_retriever" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "resource_retriever_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above  
  files.  If "resource_retriever" provides a separate development package or  
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dope/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)  


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:1118: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help. Please edit your question and provide a url to the source code for this ros package.

Comment: Please try installing `resource_retriever` using `sudo apt install ros-melodic-resource-retriever`